# Polymorphic objects with static members

Tags: c++

I have a class (MyClass) which is a subclass of an abstract class.
MyClass has got static members.
When i am deleting MyClass objects the Heap gets corrupt and i get all kinds of Memory Violation Errors.
Why is that so? Are the static members deleted or something?

```
class CAbstractClass {
public:
  CAbstractClass();
  virtual ~CAbstractClass();
...
}
```

MyClass with static member

```
class MyClass : public AbstractClass {
public:
static short    s_static;
}
```

I am Setting its value with MyClass::s_static = 2 etc.

The static member is initialized in the .cpp file

```
short MyClass::s_static=1;
```

Now i've got a list of Abstract objects where i am adding instances of MyClass (and other classes).

```
list<CAbstractClass*>   *objectList;
MyClass *myclassobj=new MyClass();
objectList->push_back(myclassobj);
```

This list is deleted like this

```
clearAll() {
    CAbstractClass *object;
    std::list<CAbstractClass*>::iterator it;
    for (it=this->objectList->begin(); !(it==this->objectList->end()); it++) {
      object=*it;
      if (object) delete object;
     }
     this->objectList->clear();
}
```

Comment: Did you try testing your hypothesis by removing the static data member?

Comment: just because it works without the static member, it doesn't mean it's correct.  have you tried some other change to memory layout? like an extra non-static member?

Comment: Try creating one instance of MyClass and delete it afterwards. If that works the cause is your list.

Comment: There's probably a memory corruption issue somewhere.  Could the same object be present several times in the list, for example?

Comment: Two other, unrelated comments on the code: first, C++ has a `!=` operator; it's not necessary (and slightly confusing) to use `!(x == y)`.  And second, `delete` is defined and well behaved on a null pointer, so there's no need for the `if` in the loop in your destructor.  (I might also mention that having a deleted pointer in a standard container is formally undefined behavior.  But it will work in all imaginable implementations, at least in contexts like yours, and IMHO, it's not worth worrying about.)

Comment: I suspect there's a bug in a destructor which is exposed by the presence of the static member.

Comment: Ok. I will put some static members back in the derived class to see if the errors are coming back then.

Comment: You were right. There's some Memory corruption caused in some other part of the program. Had nothing to do with the static members.